# FileSaver.js works for text files but not binaries

Tags: javascript, blob, filesaver.js

I have an server API and a javascript frontend that downloads files from the server. Im using FileSaver (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to save the downloaded document data to the local filesystem. The solution works well for text files but not for  the binaries. I've verified that in both cases the server sends the correct content. It's FileSaver that seems unable to save my binary content correctly. What gets saved is more or less trash, with the wrong file size.

Javascript:

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: <URL>,            
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'accept-encoding': 'identity',
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(headers());
        console.log(headers('Content-Disposition'));
        var res = headers('Content-Disposition').split('=');
        console.log(res);
        var fileName = res[1];
        console.log(fileName);
        var blob = new Blob([data]);
        saveAs(blob, fileName);
     }
```

The server side:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadDocument(@PathParam("documentId") UUID theid) {
    doc = <retrieve document>
    StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {

        public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            try {                                      
               InputStream istream = new ByteArrayInputStream(doc.getData());
               System.out.println(doc.getData().length);
               IOUtils.copy(istream, output);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(e);
            }
        }
    };

    return Response.ok(stream).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + doc.getName()).build();
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I am having the same problem downloading images from server. It only works for text based files. Any idea? Thanks!